# Edge value problems when generating bitmaps using SVG + CairoSVG

Tags: svg, colors, bitmap, polygon

Me and my team have problems with generating bitmaps out of polygons. We've tried a few different solutions in order to generate polygons sufficiently fast and have found generating SVG paths and then using CairoSVG to be the best solution for us. We are using the even-odd rule to fill the polygons. I apologies if I'm describing everything in an incorrect way in terms of vocabulary,  I'm new to SVG. The pathes are created as:

```
path_entry = f'<path fill="rgb{rgb_color}" fill-rule="evenodd" d="{svg_path}"/>'
```

With header

```
 <svg
      xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
      style="color:green;"
>
```

We only allow the bitmap to have a set of color values. The value of a pixel should be that of the polygon which it's inside. A problem we've encountered is that the edges of the polygons "splits" pixels, i.e a pixel can be both on the edge/inside of polygon A and polygon B. See the image below where the edge between the black, green and grey area gets a mixed color.

[image: The edge between the black, green and grey area gets a mixed color.]

We've currently solved this by finding each pixel that doesn't have an allowed color. We then use numpy roll to fill the value of these pixels with the value of its neighbours according to a solution found on this site.

```
 for shift in (-1,1):
            for axis in (0,1):
                a_shifted=np.roll(bitmap_only_correct_colors,shift=shift,axis=axis)
                idx=~a_shifted.mask * bitmap_only_correct_colors.mask
                bitmap_only_correct_colors[idx]=a_shifted[idx]
```

The problem with this solution is thin diagonal polygons, 1-2 pixels thick. All pixels of these polygons get the mixed value and are therefor removed. This causes the thin polygons to be partly removed creating dotted lines instead of full lines, see the image below.

[image]

**My question is:** Can we solve this problem with the edges of the polygons not getting fixed values in another way? The best solution would be to add some kind of setting to the SVG-Document before generating the images.

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Robert, it worked! Hope you have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Turn off anti-aliasing i.e. set shape-rendering="crispEdges" See the [SVG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#ShapeRenderingProperty) for more details about this CSS property.